# Is -[NSDictionary setObject:nil forKey:] the same as -[NSDictionary removeObjectForKey:]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm reading through some source code and I noticed the following API, where the developer passes in `nil` if they want an object to be removed.

```
- (void)setSomeStatus:(SomeStatusObject *)status {
    if (status != nil) {
        [store setObject:status forKey:SOME_STATUS_KEY];
    } else {
        [store removeObjectForKey:SOME_STATUS_KEY];
    }
}
```

My specific question is if the above can be reduced to

```
- (void)setSomeStatus:(SomeStatusObject *)status {
    [store setObject:status forKey:SOME_STATUS_KEY];
}
```

Or alternatively

```
- (void)setSomeStatus:(SomeStatusObject *)status {
    store[SOME_STATUS_KEY] = status;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Or even just refer to the NSMutableDictionary documentation and see what it says about trying to put nil into a dictionary

Comment: Yes, why not read the most excellent documentation?

Comment: Honestly can't make an excuse for this ha

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not equivalent. In fact, passing `nil` to `setObject:forKey:` (either the value or the key) will result in a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a value to `nil` using `setObject:forKey`.

NSDictionary wants an object, even if that object represents `NULL`, and the value alone can't be set to simply `nil`. (You could set it to `NSNULL` though).

So to answer your question, your code can't replace the existing.

Comment: The documentation for `setObject:forKey:` clearly states that passing `nil` for the object will result in a runtime exception.

Comment: Your first sentence still states you eat a value to `nil` using `setObject:forKey:`. You can't.

Comment: Whoops. That was really a mistake. I always meant to write can't but I seemed to miss the keys. My second sentence will prove that...